# Simplification of links between idele class group and étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-cohomology, galois-theory, etale-cohomology, class-field-theory

I posted this question over on stack exchange and was told it would work better here.

For interest I have been looking at links between class field theory and étale cohomology. Let $k$ be a global field. I started with the link between étale cohomology and Galois cohomology,

$H^i(\operatorname{Spec}(k)_{ét},F)\cong H^i(G_k,F_k)$

With $F$ a sheaf, $F_k$ its stalk at $\operatorname{Spec}(k^{sep}) \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$, and $G_k=Gal(k^{sep}/k)$. We can then use the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence to get the map,

$H^p(G/N,H^q(N,M))\to H^{p+q}(G,M)$

Which then, after making our group $G_k$, our module $F_k$, and our normal subgroup the commutator subgroup of $G_k$, will give us,

$H^p(G_k^{ab},H^q([G_k,G_k],F_k)) \to H^{p+q}(\operatorname{Spec}(k)_{ét},F)$

Then after applying $\hat{C}_k \cong G_k^{ab}$, with $\hat{C}_k$ being the profinite completion of the idele class group, we can finally get,

$H^p(\hat{C}_k,H^q([G_k,G_k],F_k)) \to H^{p+q}(\operatorname{Spec}(k)_{ét},F)$

as our map. If I’m not mistaken this map would be a spectral sequence. Although the connection is weird I was wondering out of interest if there is a simplification, possibly through the $H^q([G_k,G_k],F_k)$ term?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Class field theory allows you to make computations for the etale cohomology of rings of integers in number fields, which in turn generalize the statements of class field theory. See, for example, Chapter 2 of Milne's book Arithmetic Duality Theorems.